# Function to add more days to a date

Tags: javascript, angular

I don't know much about the new Date() function and I wanted a way to add days to a date.
I have

```
        this.formGeral.patchValue({data:new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10)});
```

I would like to add 5 more working days to this date (I could not count on Saturday or Sunday)
how could i change this patchvalue ?

I saw that there would be this example, but here it returns the working days too
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9281/fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-para-adicionar-mais-horas-ou-dias-a-uma-data

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
const dt = new Date();
dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 5); // adding 5 more days
this.formGeral.patchValue({data:dt});
```

You can use momentjs also
https://momentjs.com/

Example- moment().add(1, 'days'); //adds 1 day to the current date

Comment: your function is correct, but returned the error
The specified value "Sat Apr 16 2022 15:18:30 GMT-0300 (Brasilia Standard Time)" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

Comment: so before in my code i had used the
data:new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10)}

Comment: Also, please do not use momentjs. There are much better alternatives available.